# How do I add number in cell using openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I have trouble creating cells in excel using openXml. If I use Datatype Number I get a warning when opening the excel "We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?"

And if I use datatype string I get the warning inside excel.

[image]

This is the code I use...

```
        Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellId };
        row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);
        newCell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);

        newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String); // Generate warnings since number is type text in cell
        //newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number); // Generate error when open the file
        newCell.StyleIndex = 0;
```

UPDATE, If I add a decimal value like 10.2 I get this error, but if I add just 10 as value without any decimals there is no error at all. So how can I add decimals without getting this error?

Comment: What exactly is `value` here?

Comment: It is a decimal value

Comment: If it's not a requirement for the cell type to be a number type, you can set it as string. I see you are doing that, but in the wrong order (set the data type first, then the value). And also the `value.ToString()`

Comment: I believe I need to specify it as number, at least that is what excel warn about (see image above where it tell me the number is formatted as text). And it doesn't help to first set the datatype, I still get the same error when opening the file plus the warning about numbers stored as text.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with localization. The `ToString()` method of `Decimal` uses your current locale for the output. In your case that's likely a comma. OpenXML wants dots afaik.

You can force the locale to the `ToString()` method as shown in the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring).
e.g.

```cs
value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

edit. It could be that you need to do more, and convert it to scientific notation, as described [here](https://community.experianaperture.io/discussion/149/floating-point-numbers-with-microsoft-excel-open-xml-spreadsheet-xlsx-files).

Edit2: Note the existence of [`OpenXML.DecimalValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.decimalvalue?view=openxml-2.8.1)

Comment: When debuging I see that dots is used and not commas as separator so that is not the case. And I cannot see the Decimalvalue as an option in EnumValue<CellValues>? And I use the latest version 2.16.0.0